# WinterBash site exhibits some strange 404 behavior

Tags: support, bug, winter-bash, 404-not-found

I was poking around winterba.sh for secret hats and I figured there may be a secret hat linked to a URL so I decided to look at some different URLs and got plenty of 404s but, some pages throw different 404s than others. Why?

Example: http://winterba.sh/sdfj throws the classic "Page Not Found" winterbash style... but
http://winterba.sh/hat just has the text "404"

(http://winterba.sh/secret used to throw just the text "404" but since that has changed)

Still happening at 2016 with http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/hat.

Comment: Maybe `hat` is the name of a directory on the server?

Comment: true, but what would be in there? all the images and things are hosted at a diffrent domain

Comment: @DeadChex That's the `secret` LOL

Comment: @irrelephant: Seems more like a sole file then a directory for me. Maybe a joke?

Comment: I guess something to do with the URL-rewriting, "hat" is probably the name of the ASPX file although I wasn't able to prove that just yet.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out I [was right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159824/winterbash-site-exhibits-some-strange-404-behavior#comment471154_159824).

After some trial and error, I got to this: http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/hat?id=1 which returns JSON data for a specific hat.

Stack Exchange simply use this internally to load hats data.

Comment: I see a traces of russian hackers in the link :)